# For $x>1$, evaluate $\lim_{n\to \infty} \prod _{k=0} ^n \left(1+\frac{2}{x^{2^k} + x^{-2^k}}\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Simplifying the part after the product function

For $k=0$

$$\frac{x+x^{-1} +2}{x+x^{-1}}$$
$$=\frac{(x^{\frac 12}+x^{-\frac 12})^2}{x+x^{-1}}$$

Performing a similar simplification for all values of $k$, then end result is
$$\frac{1}{x^{2^k}+x^{-2^k}} (x^{\frac 12}+x^{-\frac 12})^2 (x+x^{-1})(x^2+x^{-2})...(x^{2^{k-1}}+x^{-2^{k-1}})$$

I am not able to simplify it further. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint :**

Multiply and divide by $(x^{\frac{1}{2}}-x^{−\frac{1}{2}})$
and use $(a+b)(a-b)=a^2-b^2$.

Comment: Still got nothing

Comment: I got $\frac{x^{\frac 12} + x^{-\frac 12}}{x^{\frac 12} -x^{-\frac 12}}$, but that is wrong. The right answer is $\frac{x+1}{x-1}$

Comment: @Aditya, they're the same!

Comment: Hahaha! my bad. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let $a_n$ be the product term in the limit. Note that
$$
a_{n+1}=a_n\left(1+\frac{2}{x^{2^{n+1}}+x^{-2^{n+1}}}\right)=a_n\left(\frac{(x^{2^{n}}+x^{-2^{n}})^2}{x^{2^{n+1}}+x^{-2^{n+1}}}\right)
$$

Now you can use induction to show
$$
a_n=\left(\frac{x^{1/2}+x^{-1/2}}{x^{1/2}-x^{-1/2}}\right)\left(\frac{x^{2^{n}}-x^{-2^{n}}}{x^{2^n}+x^{-2^n}}\right)
$$

Remark: The end result is the same as what you get if you follow cosmo5's hint and simplify.